# How to validate a tezos address either it's valid or invalid?

Tags: account, python

Like in web3.py we can check an ethereum address is valid or invalid by this

```
web3.utils.isAddress(address)
```

Is there any function available in pytezos or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the pyTezos documentation search feature

[image]